# Separar rows e remover bordas/espalhamento entre colunas da direita e esquerda da table com css

Tags: html, css, angular, table

Estou estilizando uma tabela pra igual uma que eu vi que achei muito bacana. Porem quando adiciono `box-shadow` fica mostrando uma borda lateral de cada coluna. e queria saber oq falta pra não mostrar, já tentei usar so border-bottom mas não me agradou.

esse é o html da minha tabela

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2em;
}

.table,
.table th,
.table td {
  border: none;
}

.table thead th {
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.table td {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.table tr td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}

.table tr td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Nome </th>
      <th> E-mail </th>
      <th class="text-center"> Ações </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of lista">
      <td>{{item.nome}}</td>
      <td>{{item.email}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <button type="button" mat-icon-button color="text-success" routerLink="editar/{{item.id}}" matTooltip="Editar"><fa-icon icon="edit"></fa-icon> </button>
        <button type="button" mat-icon-button color="text-danger" matTooltip="Deletar"><fa-icon icon="trash"></fa-icon> </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

E o resultado é esse abaixo, como podem ver nas areas que circulei, fica uma "borda", como se as colunas ainda contem espaços entre mesmo zerando o espaçamento na class .table ja deixei o box-shadow apenas com 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), porem fica uma sombra assim com os espaços entre as colunas (assim "___ ___" por exemplo). alguem tem ideia do q seja?

[tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqdVl.png)

Comment: Mauricio Furtado, não seria o caso de usar uma biblioteca de UI? Você conhece a [Material Angular](https://material.angular.io/)? Veja na [documentação exemplos de uso e estilização de tabelas](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) com essa lib. Veja se não é mais produtivo dessa forma e se for o caso dê um retorno para que possa ser melhor orientado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ja estou usando a lib angular material, inclusive estava usando a table da propria, porem eu queria estilizar a tabela com a aparência que achei bem bacana que é essa da imagem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Eu tirei a box-shadow da `.table td` e apliquei à linha inteira (a tr que contém as tds), e aqui funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Afinal, se você aplica o sombreamento às células, é normal que as sombras delimitem também as arestas internas. Mas se você aplica o sombreamento à linha inteira que contém as 3 células, ele não vai tomar conhecimento das arestas internas (pois estas não pertencem à linha-tr, e sim às células-tds). Se não era isso que você queria, comente ou faça um edit à sua pergunta.

```css
.table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2em;
}

.table,
.table th,
.table td{
  border: none;
}

.table thead th{
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.table td{
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.table tbody tr{
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.table tr td:first-child{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
.table tr td:last-child{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: vlw jovi, tentei aplicar a shadow na row e não tinha dado certo, mas agora deu kkk, adicionei tbm um border radius nessa row pra sombra pegar o arredondamento.